# takePicture() fails with Error -2147483648

Tags: android, camera

I use `Camera.Parameters#setPictureSize()` in my application to get the higher resolution image for `Camera#takePicture()`.
I use `Camera.Parameters#getSupportedPictureSizes` to get this size.

This works fine, except on a Sony Xperia S : in Logcat, the only thing I get after calling `Camera#takePicture()` is a line saying :

```
Error -2147483648
```

I finally managed to discover that the best picture size of this phone was 4000x3000, which seemed far too big for me.
Si I tried by setting the picture size manually at 1920x1080, and takePicture worked, then.

Here is my code for getting best picture size :

```
    private Camera.Size getBestPictureSize(int width, int height,
        Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "getBestPictureSize() - s(n) = "
                + size.width + "x" + size.height);
        if (result == null) {
            result = size;
        } else {
            if (size.width > result.width) {
                result = size;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, do you know a way to get the best picture size of a device, and being sure that takePicture will work as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but this is what I use in a project I'm working on.-

```
private Size getPreferredPictureSize() {
    Size res = null;
    List<Size> sizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();

    for (Size s : sizes) {
        float ratio = (float) s.width / (float) s.height;
        if (ratio == defaultCameraRatio && s.height <= PHOTO_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD) {
            res = s;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Where `defaultCameraRatio` is the aspect ratio of the default camera resolution; you can get it like this.-

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
defaultCameraRatio = (float) params.getPictureSize().width / (float) params.getPictureSize().height;
```

And `PHOTO_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD` is a 'reasonable' max height, such as 960. So, in summary, you will get a smaller resolution keeping the same aspect ratio as the default one.

Comment: Actually, I try to get the biggest resolution available for the device. So, my problem is that the biggest one on the Xperia S doesn't seem to be supported by `takePicture()`

Comment: Mm I see... Still, chances are that you're facing a memory issue, as although 4000x3000 may be an available resolution doesn't mean your device will have free memory enough to do the task.